# Get Download folder path using registry- PHP

Tags: php, registry

How to get the download folder path from registry using php?
i know how to get it using python..but now i need it by using php

## python snippet to get the download path using registry

```
with OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders') as key:
Downloads = QueryValueEx(key, '{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}')[0]
```

Comment: Php can't get download path registry of `client`.

Comment: Because PHP runs on the Server and not the Client

Comment: oh okay! @Saad & RiggsFolly

Comment: i have a image.png in my server and i have to move it to client's download folder using get and put_content() so i needed the download folder path(generic) ...

Comment: No you cannot. You can only send the file to the browser. The user must decide to save it, and tell the browser where to save it too. If you could do that we would all be part of one huge Bot Net

Comment: But i have moved the image from server to client machine using php's get and Put_content() method but the path to download folder i.e, the destination path was static and not generic

Comment: Do you mean `file_put_content()` ??

Comment: yes i meant file_put_content()

Comment: That does not place anything onto the clients machine. Be careful when testing. Just because it looks like it works when your test server is on your PC does not mean it would work when the client was running on a remote machine

Comment: so whats the alternative can i do to put image.png in clients download folder using php

Comment: What is your objective to achieve it? I seriously doubt on it as it could be spam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not get downloaded folder path using PHP. As discussed in the comments, PHP runs on the server and once it starts flushing the file to download in the browser, it can not know what is happening on the client's side.

Could you please explain further, why you want downloaded folder path?

Comment: i needed it to put a image.png to the clients download path and then run my .py script which is in exe(converted) on the local site which they will have already downloaded...in short it is an dependency for my exe

Comment: Are you creating a desktop application using PHP or what?

Comment: no, we have created exe using python script now for the exe to run we need the an image.png to be in the downloads folder path (generic).the image.png will be in the server and we need the php to transfer it to the clients downloads path

Comment: You can download the image using Python script and store in client's location. Can't you? PHP is a general purpose server side executable language actually.

Comment: yeah!! I binded it to the exe itself using pyinstaller